# How to get the value of a regex capture group?

Tags: c#, regex

First of all sorry about the tittle. Didn't know how to explain it.
This is my code:

```
string sString = @"docs/horaires/1/images/1"
var PickImage = Regex.Matches(sString, "/horaires/(.*?)/images/");
Console.WriteLine(PickImage[0].Value);
```

This will print `/horaires/1/images/` instead of `1`. I tried all the `RegexOptions` but didn't find the solution in there.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Use `PickImage[0].Groups[1].Value`

Comment: I was going to change "patter" to "pattern" in the title, but there already is a post with that same title.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon then you could try to find a better title - I just did that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
string sString = @"docs/horaires/1/images/1";
var pickImage = Regex.Match(sString, @"/horaires/(.*?)/images/");

if (pickImage.Success)
    Console.WriteLine(pickImage.Groups[1].Value);
```

In your original code, `PickImage[0]` is a `Match` object, and `Value` will return the *full* match. You want the first captured group, so use `match.Groups[1].Value`. Note that `Groups[0]` always contains the full match.

No need to use `Matches` is you want a single result, use `Match` instead.